# Parse XML in python Sharepoint output having namespaces

Tags: python, xml, sharepoint, xml-parsing

I need the output of the z:row along from the xmlfile which is received as response from Sharepoint

I need the output as

```
Title dept
test  hr
gang  ht
```

The input i got as xmlfile is

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:ABCDDC" xmlns:dt="uuid:REDSD" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
    <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
        <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="30">
            <s:AttributeType name="Title" rs:name="Title" rs:number="1">
                <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512"/>
            </s:AttributeType>
        <s:AttributeType name="dept" rs:name="dept" rs:number="1">
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512"/>
        </s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row Title="test" dept="hr" />
<z:row Title="gang" dept="ht" />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Comment: With the namespace the parsing doesnt work and i am new to python any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lxml` package to find all the data nodes like so:

```
from lxml import etree

xml_tree = etree.parse("file.xml")

data_nodes = xml_tree.findall("//{#RowsetSchema}row")

for node in data_nodes:
    print node.get('Title'), node.get("dept")
```

Finding the particular node you want can get tricky sometimes because of the namespaces associated with them. You'd think you want the `"row"` node but it is actually `"{#RowsetSchema}row"`. If you want to check what are the namespaces associated with each nodes, you can use the `iter()` method on the `xml_tree` and print tag names.

**Example:**

```
for node in xml_tree.iter():
    print node.tag
```